# Why is the data displayed only through the map in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I only need to display the data of one object that I get here

```
const {posts, loading} = useSelector((state) => ({...state.posts}))
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getPost(id))
}, []);
```

"posts" is array

when I want to display it simply this way

```
<h4>cat: {posts[0].category}</h4>
<h4>aut: {posts[0].username}</h4>
```

it only works only for the first time and after one page refresh the array (posts) turns out to be empty. But when I do it like this

```
<>
  {
    posts.map(post=>(
         <CardDetailsComponent post={post} key={post._id}/>
             ))
  }
</>
```

(CardDetails component looks exactly like first example but in different component)

everything is fine. Why?

Comment: Can you reproduce an example in a code sandbox

Comment: @Sean here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-beaver-fwip9o?file=/src/App.js but in sand box it works fine. The problem is when I use it without map function(exactly how its in sand box). Array(posts) after first reload turns out to be empty

Comment: its full code of component where problem appears maybe it will be useful https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-snowflake-ms0tji?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Sean I found that doesn't mean in what component I use map or not problem appears in array when I want to take first object using posts[0] after first reload with this in code whole array disappears. If I use just post there Is no problem but I can't get any objects from array

Comment: problem solved just added "?" so its posts[0]?.category